# Vulkan - Rendering into multi-planar YUV render target

Tags: vulkan, yuv, rendertarget

I didn't find in Vulkan spec anything to support or against:
Is it possible to render to a YUV420p format render target texture ?
And if so, does vulkan convert from RGB given in the fragment shader output to YUV of the render target?